# ElasticSearch in Grails, search return no results when domain field has value with @ character

Tags: grails, search, elasticsearch, searchable

I encountered a problem when I was changing Searchable plugin to ElasticSearch plugin (:elasticsearch:0.0.3.8) for Grails (2.4.4).

Let's say that I have domain object and a service:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email

    static constraints = {
        id bindable: true
        firstName blank: false
        lastName blank: false
        email blank: false, unique: true, email: true
    }

   static searchable = {
        root true
        only = ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email']
    }
}

class SearchService {

    List<Person> findPersons(String searchPhrase) {
        Innovator.search(searchPhrase + '*').searchResults
    }
}
```

My Config.groovy file contains following config:

```
elasticSearch {
    client.mode = 'local'
    index.store.type = 'memory'
    date.formats = []
    defaultExcludedProperties = ["password"]
    disableAutoIndex = false
    datastoreImpl = 'hibernateDatastore'
    bulkIndexOnStartup = true
    maxBulkRequest = 500
}
```

Suppose that we have following person in DB:

```
Person(firstName: 'Julius', lastName: 'Caesar', email: 'julius.caesar@domain.com')
```

Now, when I invoke findPersons('Julius') or findPersons('Caesar') or findPersons('Jul') etc. then as a result I get list with one Person object.
But when I try to search using phrase with '@' character for example: findPersons('julius.caesar@doma') or findPersons('julius.caesar@domain.com') I do not receive any results, hovever findPersons('julius.caesar') is ok.
Analogical code in Searchable plugin works correct.

I've tried to remove '*' character and it didn't help.

As workaround I changed searchable closure to:

```
static searchable = {
    root true
    email index : 'not_analyzed'
    only = ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email']
}
```

and findPersons method to:

```
List<Person> findPersons(String searchPhrase) {
    if(!searchPhrase.contains('@'){
        searchPhrase += '*'
    }
    Innovator.search(searchPhrase).searchResults
}
```

Now I can use findPersons('julius.caesar@domain.com') to find Person object. But this is exact value and I would like to use also prefix search for email field.
For example: findPersons('julius.caesar@doma') should also return Person as a result.

Thank you for any tips and any help in solving this issue.

Regards,
Kamil